# Run bash script unless get desired result from above command

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I just want bash script that will run in loop unless get the desired result.

for example

I run a command and i want to desired output of command is 8. So i just want to run the same command again and again unless result is equal to 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will run `command` until the output is `8`

```
n=
until [[ "$n" -eq 8 ]]; do n=$(command); done
```

Comment: Thanks.

Also i have used diff login that works fine for me 
completed=$(command)

while [ $completed -ne 8 ]; do completed=$(command); done